# Running RabbitMQ java client

Tags: java, maven, rabbitmq

I want to create a RabbitMQ java client. I created a Maven project like this:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=rabbitmq-test -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Inside the pom.xml file i added (as described in their site)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
  <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and inside the single main file i wrote:

```
package com.mycompany.app;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;


/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App
{
        public static void main( String[] args ) throws java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException, java.io.IOException {

                ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
                factory.setHost("localhost");
                Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
                Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
        }
}
```

Without the RabbitMQ stuff inside the code i run

```
mvn package
java -cp target/rabbitmq-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.App
```

and code runs fine.
If i include the imports and the RabitMQ code then if i run like before i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory
    at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:17)
```

Which basically means "Can't find the RabitMQ jar" Right?
but on my first `mvn package` run, maven downloaded amqp-client-4.0.0.jar somewhere. So how do i add this jar as well to the run?

I tried to download this jar myself and when i run like this:

```
java -cp target/rabbitmq-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:target/amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:. com.mycompany.app.App
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
```

So i downloaded this jar, and when i run like this:

```
java -cp target/rabbitmq-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:target/amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:target/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar:. com.mycompany.app.App
```

i get:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I added

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

but still the same...
So what's the problem? besides of me being clueless on java?

EDIT:
On the RabbitMQ logs i see:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2-Dec-2016::15:18:18 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.1713.0> (127.0.0.1:55976 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
```

when i get the staticLoggerBinder error. So What does that mean? what's happenin?

Comment: You need to have all JARs your code is using on the classpath when you execute your main class

Comment: @LutzHorn yes but what's the missing jar here?

Comment: The one that contains `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder`. See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder

Comment: @LutzHorn That solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: A simple web search can sometimes be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define configuration "jar-with-dependencies" under maven-assembly-plugin in your POM. So maven will include all the required jars inside your package itself when you run with package goal.

Otherwise you have to give all the required jars manually.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add dependencies For RabbitMQ in your pom.xml file check the below dependencies code

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mmi</groupId>
  <artifactId>PushNotification</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
        <spring.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId> 
            <version>${spring.version}</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```